# How do I sell my prisoner into slavery?

Tags: rimworld

I have a prisoner that I don't want to care for, and a slave trader in comms range. How do I sell the prisoner to the slave trader? I can see the prisoner show up in the trade screen, but I cant figure out how to actually sell him.

[image]

Comment: After seeing this title in the _"Hot Network Questions"_ sidebar, I'm glad this was asked in Gaming StackExchange and not elsewhere.

Comment: This stack has the best question titles *ever*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drag the quantity in the "Drag to trade" column towards the slave trader, the same as you sell any other goods to traders.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. I drag the `1` to the  `0` on the right of it, but doesn't change anything. I added a picture for clarity

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the prisoner does NOT need to be next to an orbital beacon, right?

Comment: No orbital beacon necessary AFAIK. I'm assuming they're in a jail cell though?

Comment: Also - what happens when you try to buy one of the slaves (repeating the motion, but to the left)?

Comment: Yes, he is in a prison cell. And  dragging to buy stuff doesn't seem to work either (though I have no money)

Comment: Wait, I think I know what's wrong. You're clicking the 1 - you should be clicking the rightmost number (currently zero) and dragging to the right. (The "Drag to Trade" column)